# Getting logged on user's name with or without domain in Windows

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Is there a direct API to get the currently logged in user's name with the domain? So, it would return something like "domain\user" when a machine is on the domain, but at the same time it would return "user" when the machine is not on the domain? If there's not, what's the best way to get this information?

I noticed there's a LookupAccountName function - would that be the right direction to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GetUserNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435(VS.85).aspx). It supports various name formats.

Comment: I personally haven't gotten it to work. One needs to include the `security.h` system header, but then the compiler is told by `sspi.h` to error with `Define  SECURITY_WIN32, SECURITY_KERNEL or` and even when defining `SECURITY_WIN32` the compiler isn't able to proceed, encountering a lot of errors in `sspi.h`. My Visual Studio 2017 setup is rather vanilla and the project settings aren't touched. I went back to using `GetUserName` instead.